# How to populate field with data 2 levels down?

Tags: apex

We have a scenario of accounts who have contacts where some have one or more records in a custom object named members__c but not all contacts have a member__c record. member__c object has a lookup relationship with the contact object.

How to select all contacts who have at least one member__c record and insert their first and last name in a field named "member__c" on the account object?

Comment: What have you tried so far in order to get your contacts and where are you having difficulty getting the related members__c info? Are you starting from Contact or from Account? Please show your code.

Comment: This is my attempt but I get a syntax error. SELECT Account.Name,(SELECT Contact.Name (SELECT BOG_Member__c.Name FROM Member__c) FROM contacts) FROM Account WHERE 
Account.Name LIKE '%washington%'

Comment: You can't have a subquery within a subquery, thus the syntax error. They need to be separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps aggregate querying will help. Something like below.

```
List<AggregateResult> aggregates = [
    SELECT
        Contact__r.AccountId accountId,
        Contact__r.FirstName first,
        Contact__r.LastName last
    FROM Members__c WHERE Contact__r.AccountId = :accountid
    GROUP BY Contact__r.AccountId, Contact__r.FirstName, Contact__r.LastName
];

Map<Id, Account> parentRecords = new Map<Id, Account>();
for (AggregateResult aggregate : aggregates)
{
    Id parentId = (Id)aggregate.get('accountId');
    String firstName = (String)aggregate.get('first');
    String lastName = (String)aggregate.get('last');
    parentRecords.put(parentId, new Account(
        Id = parentId, Member__c = firstName + ' ' + lastName
    ))
}
update parentRecords.values();
```

Comment: I found my error. Nothing to do with you. It works great. Thanks Adrian.

Comment: @adrianlarson do we really need an aggregate query for this case?

Comment: Need? No it just seemed most efficient. I don't think you can do it with just one query otherwise.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Why not use `List<Member__c> = [SELECT
        Contact__r.AccountId accountId,
        Contact__r.FirstName first,
        Contact__r.LastName last
    FROM Members__c WHERE Contact__r.AccountId = :accountid]` and iterate over it to get the first name,last name of the contact and it's associated contact's accountid?. Just trying to understand the need of using aggregate query here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect your query to look something like the following:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Member__r, ContactId__r (SELECT Name, AccountId, Member__  
    FROM contacts), (SELECT Id, BOG_Member__c.Name, ContactId, FROM Member__r)
       FROM Account WHERE Account.Name LIKE '%washington%'
```

From the above you should be able to create maps of Account.Id to ContactId and ContactId to Member__c.Id

Comment: My reading of the OP is that `Member` is a child of `Contact` and not `Account`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson. Yes, that was my understanding as well. Member is a grandchild of Account, but also related to Contact via the ContactId. It would seem the relationships above would provide the criteria needed to query it because of those two relationships.

Comment: But then you try to subquery member from account. That's a different architecture.

Comment: @AdrianLarson True, but it also has a lookup to Account as well making it a related object with a different child dependency to Account. You might say there's a double bind I think is the correct term for it.

Comment: Hmm not sure where you see that. Did I miss it in one of the comments?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Last sentence of question, 2nd paragraph. BTW, did you ever get the notice of my question to you from the chat room?

Comment: Rereading his question, what I have may not return the desired results. Would seem there might be a need to add a where clause on Member__r. Would want to test this in my Dev Org to see what's really required.

Comment: No chat room notice. You could do an inne -join if there's a direct relationship, I just didn't think there was one.